# How can I roll damage via chat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, tools, fantasy-grounds

I'm DMing a Pathfinder game on Fantasy Grounds where one of the players rolls a lot of damage via the text box using /die (For example, /die 1d4).

I'd like to be able to drag the result of the rolls to characters on the combat tracker like the results of damage rolls made from the character sheet. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up e-mailing Fantasy Grounds support. It turns out for the "/die" rolls you can just drag it directly to the combat tracker rather than dropping it onto the tokens (like you can with damage from sheets).

For example:

/die 2d4 => 3

Dragging the 3 to the "Wnd" column in the Combat Tracker will apply the damage.

Comment: You can also just type /help in the chat and a bunch of options come up for you.